# UNITY2D: Choosing between two objects with same TAG and same LAYER

Tags: unity-game-engine, triggers, selection

[image]

I have this situation:

The Player Object has a collider with a trigger detector which selects the object and the variable of objects of a certain TAG.

When the player object is on a space occupied by 2 objects with this certain tag it has to choose which of these objects is going to select: The one with the higher "A".

How do I make the player object to make this selection?

Comment: Depends, which why do you want him to select and why?

Comment: When you figure out which you want him to select, and a good reason as to why he should always select that one over the other, then you can find a way to code it.  For example if you want him to select Object 1 because its closer, you create a variable to store the currently selected ones distance,  then when you hit the case there is 2 you select the closer one.  If you want object 2 because its a value is higher, same thing instead of distance base it on the higher value of a.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can collide with multiple objects at once.

Then you want to always "select" the one with highest `A`.

I would store all valid (correct layer + correct tag + script is attached) collisions and then you can easily update the selection whenever there is a new collision or a collision ended.

probably something like

```c#
// Here you store all current colliders and the according reference 
// of the attached component YourScript
private Dictionary<Collider, YourScript> currentColliders = new Dictionary<Collider, YourScript>();

// Here you store references for the currently selected object
private YourScript currentlySelected;
private Collider currentlySelectedCollider;

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    // First check for the tag
    if(other.CompareTag("YOURTAG"))
    {
        // Then try to get the component
        if(other.TryGetComponent<YourScript>(out var script))
        {
            // First store this new pair in the dictionary for later 
            currentColliders.Add(other, script);

            // Then check if there is either no selection yet
            // or the new collision has a higher A
            if(!currentlySelected || script.A > currentlySelected.A)
            {
                // If so -> you have a new Winnner
                OnNewObjectSelected(other, script);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void OnNewObjectSelected (Collider collider, YourScript script)
{
    currentlySelected = script;
    currentlySelectedCollider = collider;

     if(!currentlySelected || !currentlySelectedCollider) return;

    // Evtl do something with the new selection
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    // Again first check the tag
    if(other.CompareTag("YOURTAG"))
    {
        // Remove this object from the dictionary as it is not colliding anymore
        if(currentColliders.ContainsKey(other))
        {
            currentColliders.Remove(other);
        }

        // Then check if this is the current selection
        if(other == currentSelectedCollider)
        {
            // If so update the current selection with the next highest A
            // among the existing collisions
            Collider newSelection = null;
            foreach(var kvp in currentColliders)
            {
                // Skip null entries (e.g. if the object was destroyed)
                if(!kvp.Value) continue;

                // of there is no newSelection yet or this has a higher A as the current one
                if(!newSelection || kvp.Value.A > currentColliders[newSelection].A)
                {
                    newSelection = kvp.Key;
                }
            }

            // check if any selection left
            if(newSelection)
            {
                // you have a new Winner
                OnNewObjectSelected (newSelection, currentColliders[newSelection]);
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise reset the current selection
                OnNewObjectSelected(null, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

For checking also the layer you can either add a

```c#
public LayerMask checkLayers;
```

and change both

```c#
if(other.CompareTag("YOURTAG"))
```

to

```c#
if(other.CompareTag("YOURTAG") && checkLayers == (checkLayers | (1 << other.gameObject.layer))
```

Or you could go to the Physics Settings and in the Collision Matrix make sure that anyway your main object can only collide with the specific layers.

---

**Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear**